# Installing numpy 1.21.0 on EC2 instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, numpy, amazon-ec2, installation

I am trying to install numpy 1.21.0 (which is a dependency for a project I am working on) on an EC2 instance. Using pip, I can only install up to version 1.19.5, which is the highest version provided in that environment.

I have also tried the following:

- install directly from wheel -> none of the distributions match the architecture
- install using conda -> version not available
- install with conda-forge -> installation hangs

What else could I try? Alternatively, is there a EC2 instance which comes preconfigured for machine-learning projects?

Comment: What Instance Type are you using? Can you Edit your question to show what you tried doing, and what errors were received?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I installed the Numpy 1.21.0 package on the Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM):

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-25-7 ~]$ pip3 install numpy==1.21.0
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting numpy==1.21.0
  Downloading numpy-1.21.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 15.7 MB 24.8 MB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.21.0
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-25-7 ~]$ python3
Python 3.7.10 (default, Jun  3 2021, 00:02:01)
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-13)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> print(numpy.__version__)
1.21.0
```

Comment: Yes, that would be the normal way, but it didn't work on that particular EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

From [Amazon Deep Learning AMIs](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/amis/):

> The AWS Deep Learning AMIs provide machine learning practitioners and researchers with the infrastructure and tools to accelerate deep learning in the cloud, at any scale. You can quickly launch Amazon EC2 instances pre-installed with popular deep learning frameworks and interfaces such as TensorFlow, PyTorch, Apache MXNet, Chainer, Gluon, Horovod, and Keras to train sophisticated, custom AI models, experiment with new algorithms, or to learn new skills and techniques.

See also: [New AWS Deep Learning AMIs for Machine Learning Practitioners | AWS Machine Learning Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/new-aws-deep-learning-amis-for-machine-learning-practitioners/)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, John. These AMIs look quite good in terms of the ML preconfig. However, the ones I checked also don't allow installation of numpy > 1.19.5 using pip.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't allow"? What did you do, and what happened? Did you use `sudo pip3 install ...`?

Comment: This particular version is not available for installation with pip. This highest version available is 1.19.5